# Search Results Tag Pair - Limiting Results

Tags: simple-search

How do you limit the amount of results on the...

> {exp:search:search_results}

tag pair. I can see nothing in the EE documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search module results are controlled not via the `search_results` tag, but via the ["results" parameter on the search form](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/simple.html#results).

Answer (score 2):

The Simple Search module is rather...erm...simple, so the options are limited but you can use the results parameter on the search_form tag:

```
{exp:search:simple_form 
    channel="my_channel" 
    status="open"
    results="10"
    result_page="search/results"
}
```

This will limit the results to 10 per page for example but you can then just leave off the pagination (so no more pages are visible) and you'll have your 10 results only.

Comment: Many thanks that is very helpful. I was wondering if I wanted to use pagination with my results what is the correct method for doing this?

Comment: I see you posted another question with regards to pagination. Did that solve things for you or are you still having problems?